# Advice about the copyright in research work as a research associate

Tags: authorship, copyright, research-assistantship, intellectual-property

I need advice regarding the copyright of the work done as a research associate.

I am working for a university as a research associate and my principal investigator insists on publishing my work without my consent. She thinks that she is entitled to do so because i worked on her idea and she paid me the salary. So she has a right to publish my work without my consent and I have no right on that work any more.

Is this true?

Comment: Depends on the wording of your contract, but it is possible (it would be standard for industry contracts). Depending on jurisdiction, you may retain the right to have your name mentioned as originator of the work ("moral rights", they are usually given up in the contract in the US but inalienable in other places, e.g. France).